# Shortcut for opening current object in Object Inspector

Tags: spyder

I believe there is a shortcut in Spyder to open the current object (i.e. the object where the flashing text cursor is) in the Object Inspector.

What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean "inspect current object"? The default in the console is Ctrl+I.

Menu -> Tools -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts and then find the name in the table in the right part of the window.