# Shortcut for closing Object inspector in Spyder 3

Tags: python, spyder

The shortcut for [opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667431/shortcut-for-opening-current-object-in-object-inspector) the object inspector in Spyder 3 is Ctrl+I.

Is there a shortcut to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) No, there isn't a shortcut for closing the *Object Inspector* (called *Help* since Spyder 3.0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I use the Help as substitute to typing [function?] in the console, so it would be nice to close it using keyboard after I have finished consulting the docs

Comment: This is your particular use case, and you're the only one requesting this feature in seven years I've been working in Spyder. So I don't think we're going to implement it, sorry.

Comment: Absolutely, it was just to add some context to my question. In general is the Help supposed to replace the [?] in the console or there's more to it?

Comment: It is the equivalent of `?` but it's supposed to be there all the time.